# $timeout.flush TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, timeout, angular-promise

I have a segment of code inside a $timeout which executes a promise.
When i write the unit test for that i use $timeout.flush() and i can go inside the $timeout block. The promise is then resolved (since $timeout calls $scope.$apply() internally) but then after the method code finishes and bubbles up to jasmine i get the error TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of undefined.
Anyone else experienced this before?

Controller Code:

```
$scope.timeoutFunction = function(){
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.callFunction().then(function () {
            callAnotherFunction();
        });
    }, 0);
}
```

Unit test code:

```
$scope.timeoutFunction();

scope.$digest(); // not needed

$timeout.flush(); // even tried $timeout.flush(0);
```

Also if i mock the timeout to be a callback function it works.
Example:

```
function mockedTimeout() {
    arguments[0]();
}

$timeout = mockedTimeout;
```

Then we just use the $scope.$digest for the promises to be called, timeout runs immediately. Could it be angular bug?

Complete error stack:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of undefined
at n.$get.n.$digest (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\Libs\Angular\angular.min.js:124:101)
at n.$get.n.$apply (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\Libs\Angular\angular.min.js:126:293)
at Object.fn (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\Libs\Angular\angular.min.js:139:3)
at Function.angular.mock.$Browser.self.defer.flush (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\TDD\angular-mocks.js:127:42)
at Function.angular.mock.$TimeoutDecorator.$delegate.flush (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\TDD\angular-mocks.js:1732:28)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:51679/Tests.js:254:18)
at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\jasmine.js:1064:17)
at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\jasmine.js:2096:31)
at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\jasmine.js:2049:8)
at jasmine.Spec.execute (http://localhost:51679/referenceFile?path=D:\development\Projects\WebSite\Scripts\jasmine.js:2376:14)"
```

Comment: I'm running into this issue now. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.